# How to safely 'override' existing syntax highlighting file?

Tags: vimscript, syntax-highlighting

Okay the `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/sh.vim` file that came with my system was apparently buggy, so I want to replace it with [the version by "Dr. Chip"](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/syntax/)

I know that I really should not edit the files under `/usr/share/vim/` directory, so can I 'override' the buggy version with the new version by simply sticking the (new) `sh.vim` file somewhere?

Comment: Add it to `~/.vim/syntax`?

Comment: The version in `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax` is by "Dr. Chip" too.  It's just an older version of the file.

Comment: Yep, the one already existing is much older than the one available on Dr. Chip's site. I forgot exact version, but IIRC the "Last Change" was in 2013 or something.

Answer (score 5):

When you enter the command `:help syn-file` they say:

> 1. Create your user runtime directory.   You would normally use the first item
>      of the 'runtimepath' option.  Example for Unix: 
>      `mkdir ~/.vim`
> 2. Create a directory in there called "syntax".  For Unix: 
>      `mkdir ~/.vim/syntax`
> 3. Write the Vim syntax file.  Or download one from the internet.  Then write
>      it in your syntax directory.  For example, for the "mine" syntax: 
>      `:w ~/.vim/syntax/mine.vim`
>
> Now you can start using your syntax file manually: 
>    `:set syntax=mine`
>   You don't have to exit Vim to use this.

I think that should do the trick for your problem.

Also I'm not sure how buggy is your original file but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7451388/4194289) may interest you. For the tl;dr version: including the first line `#!/bin/bash` (or whatever is the shell you're using) helps vim to determine which syntax should be used (but I don't know if it is relevant in your case).